# .onTapGesture not working for the custom view

Tags: swiftui

I have view displaying a number and updating a status according to the state of a button:

```
struct View: View
{
    var nb: Int
    @State private var isSelected = false

    init(nb: Int)
    {
        self.nb = nb
    }

    func updateIsSelected()
    {
        if (isSelected == true)
        {
            isSelected = false
        }
        else
        {
            isSelected = true
        }
    }

    func getIsSelected() -> Bool
    {
        return self.isSelected
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Button("\(nb))",
                   action:
                   {
                    updateIsSelected()
                   })
        }
    }
}
```

This view is constituting another one, in which I show several View():

```
struct Panel: View
{
    var listView = [View(nb: 1), View(nb: 2), View(nb: 3), View(nb: 4)]

    func getSelected() -> Int
    {
        var index: Int = -1

        for i in 0 ..< listView.count
        {
            if (listView[i].getIsSelected() == true)
            {
                index = i
            }
        }
                print(index)
        return index
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView(.horizontal)
        {
            HStack
            {
                ForEach(0 ..< listView.count)
                {
                    index in listView[index]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, this panel is displayed in my HomeView() such as:

```
private var panel = Panel()
...
VStack
{
    self.panel.onTapGesture
    {
        self.getSelected()
    }
} 
...
```

I need to get the index of the selected View whenever the user tap the panel. For some reasons, the onTapGesture is not working as I was expecting Even a simple print() inside of it is not trigged.

I also noticed that, tapping on the button does nothing. However, if I manage to tap precisely on the edge of the ScrollView, the method to retrieve the index of the selected one is triggered.

What is wrong here that makes is so difficult to access my elements?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the button intercepts click events.
You can add `.simultaneousGesture` to `self.panel` to combine the click handling, but you will get -1 every time because `TapGesture` will be executed before the button action `updateIsSelected` is called.
But for example you can create let in `Panel` and pass closure which will return the value of the clicked item.

```
struct Panel: View {
    var listView = [View(nb: 1), View(nb: 2), View(nb: 3), View(nb: 4)]

    let tap: (Int) -> ()     // <---- Here

    <...>

    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView(.horizontal)
        {
            HStack
            {
                ForEach(0 ..< listView.count)
                {
                    index in listView[index]
                        .simultaneousGesture(      // <---- Here
                            TapGesture()
                                .onEnded {
                                    tap(listView[index].nb)
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your `HomeView` will be

```
private var panel = Panel(tap: { number in
    print(number)
})

...

    VStack
    {
        self.panel
    }
...
```